# Answering your own question after 22 hours

Tags: discussion, self-answer

There seems to a be time frame (22 hours) within which I can answer my own question and mark it as correct. Take a look at this question:

[Imap folder only returning a subset of emails with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357433/imap-folder-only-returning-a-subset-of-emails-with-it/5365038#5365038)

What is the correct next step here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's to give someone else time to post an answer.

If you post a question to which you already know the answer (it is allowed) then if you could post and accept your own answer immediately it would discourage others from posting thus nullifying the point of the site.

I've had a case where I posted thinking I knew the "right" answer but someone came along and posted a better one.

Just be patient.

Answer (score 7):

1. Wait
2. Accept your own answer

Also, be sure to upvote the other answer if it ultimately helped you find the solution.